# Joomla Akeeba/Kickstart strange "ajax"? behaviour (error 403)

Tags: ajax, apache, joomla3.0

I want to restore a Joomla! 3.0 site from an Akeeba backup taken from my computer (localhost) to an online web server. I have used many versions of kickstart all giving the same problem. The latest I have used is 4.1.

I upload the kickstart files as well as the .jpa file (via FTP) to the server. The permissions are 744.

The problem is that kickstart screen appears and when I press start it continues with the error:

> AN ERROR OCCURRED
>
> AJAX Loading Error HTTP Status: 403 (Forbidden) Internal status: error
>   XHR ReadyState: undefined Raw server response:
>
> Forbidden
>
> **You don't have permission to access /kickstart.php on this server.**
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But kickstart.php was just accessed and used to start the procedure!
As we can see in the Firebug the file is accessed twice before the error occurs.
[image: Firebug screenshot]

**EDIT**: I must also inform you that I completely removed the .htaccess file so that I wouldn't have concerns that it would be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I could give you is that you need to change the permissions to `755`:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/yourserver.com/public_html
```

and own the files

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/yourserver.com/public_html
```

Comment: This shouldn't solve the problem, because the restoration runs the first steps and then the error occurs. However I can try to fix the permissions from the panel, since I do not have shell access to the server.